# reduction of independence problem and cluster problem

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, reductions

independent problem is: there is a simple and undirected graph, we are looking for the maximum vertex in which there is no edge between any two of them.

cluster problem is: there is a simple and undirected graph, we are looking for the maximum number of the vertex in which there are proximity every two vertexes ( there is an edge between any two vertexes)

how can I reduct independent problem to cluster problem and vise versa?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, given $G$, build a graph $G'$ where $V(G)=V(G')$ and for every $v,u\in V(G)$, $(v,u)\in E(G')\iff(v,u)\notin E(G)$

Comment: for reducing cluster problem to independent, it works, but for the opposite direction, I didn't get it how it can be the answer

Comment: Also known as the complement graph $\overline G$.